# .htaccess mod_rewrite works only with www

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a .htaccess file in a subdirectory of a site I'm working on.  It works as I want when the URL begins with www, but if www is missing, it doesn't work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /media
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]+)/?$ index.php?a=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_\s\-]+)$ index.php?a=$1&b=$2 [L]
```

If I request http://www.mysite.com/media/test, it works, but http://mysite.com/media/test doesn't.  What am I missing?

Comment: There must be something else going on here. Are you sure that www.mysite.com and mysite.com both are mapped to the same directories in your Apache config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with your rewrite rules, this probably has something to do with the way your DNS is configured.

Try to ping both domains: with and without 'www'.

Here's what I do: I configure my DNS so that *everything* **with or without www** is redirected to the same PC:

[image: DNS configuration]

Then I handle everything through vhost configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@livrepizzas.fr
    DocumentRoot "/web/htdocs/olivier/livrepizzas/dev/website"

    ServerName livrepizzas.fr
    ServerAlias *.livrepizzas.fr
    ...
    ...
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://website.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=permanent,QSA,L]
```

Try that